# i want to write mysql query

Tags: mysql

Print the Level and the average age of students for that Level, for all Levels except JR.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
    sid NUMERIC(6) NOT NULL,
    sname VARCHAR(15),
    major VARCHAR(20),
    level VARCHAR(2),
    sage NUMERIC(2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (sid)
);

INSERT INTO STUDENT (sid, sname, major, level, sage) values (1,'JOHN','EE','FR' ,18);
INSERT INTO STUDENT (sid, sname, major, level, sage) values (2,'TIM','EE','FR',19);
INSERT INTO STUDENT (sid, sname, major, level, sage) values (3,'RICHARD','EE','SO',20);
INSERT INTO STUDENT (sid, sname, major, level, sage) values (4,'EDWARD','EE','SO',21);
INSERT INTO STUDENT (sid, sname, major, level, sage) values (5,'ALBER','CS','JR',22);
INSERT INTO STUDENT (sid, sname, major, level, sage) values (6,'MARY','EE','JR',22);
INSERT INTO STUDENT (sid, sname, major, level, sage) values (7,'JACK','EE','SR',23);
INSERT INTO STUDENT (sid, sname, major, level, sage) values (8,'JULIAN','EE','SR',22);
INSERT INTO STUDENT (sid, sname, major, level, sage) values (9,'SAM','EE','SR',24);
INSERT INTO STUDENT (sid, sname, major, level, sage) values (10,'RAM','CS','SR',23);
INSERT INTO STUDENT (sid, sname, major, level, sage) values (11,'RICK','EE','SR',24);
```

Comment: Nuh uh. You write it, then come back with a specific question.

Comment: you should really show what you have tried

Answer (score 2):

```
  SELECT level, AVG(sage) AS AvgAge
    FROM STUDENT
   WHERE level != 'JR'
GROUP BY level
```

Comment: +0 giving that man a fish at lightning speed!

Comment: @hexparrot I guess I was feeling generous. :)

Comment: I understand entirely; I too am guilty sometimes to quickly demonstrate the best answer even if it sometimes short-circuits the process.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT level, AVG(sage) 
    FROM STUDENT
    WHERE level <> 'JR' 
    GROUP BY level
```